# Можно ли сделать выведения комментов в php без перезагрузки страницы, или перезагрузке, но не ухадящая в самое начало страницы сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Появился такой вот вопрос: как сделать чтобы при перезагрузке страницы пользователь оставался на том месте, где он и был при написания, например, комментария? т.е. я при написания комментария, и отправки его, у меня постоянно перезагружается страница, и я оказываюсь на самом верху сайта, а нужно чтобы я оставался на том месте где и писал коммент.

```
session_start();
include_once("settings.php");

$sql = sprintf("SELECT comment_text FROM comments WHERE id_post = '$post' ORDER BY id_comment");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<div class = "row comment pt-2"><div class = "col-md-1"><img class = "avatar" src = "../assets/images/user.png"></div><div class = "comment col-md-11">'.
    $row['comment_text'].'</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: просто используй ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

самый простейший вариант: оборачиваешь комментарии в div с атрибутом id, например

```
<div id="comments">
    ... здесь твои комментарии
</div>
```

На форме в качестве экшена указываешь адрес с якорем, например

```
<form action="/post.php#comments">
... тело формы
</form>
```

Когда браузеру приходит URL с якорем (#...), он ищет на странице элемент с таким id и скроллит до него.

Другой вариант, если освоишь JavaScript, можно отослать запрос на сервер без перезагрузки с помощью AJAX.

Comment: А как это можно сделать через jqury? Извини, за такие, возможно, глупые вопросы, просто js совсем не понимаю...